# Print all nodes in a hierarchy if at least one node is active

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, hierarchical-data

A table EMPLOYEE has below structure with 5 Million rows (5 * 10<sup>6</sup>).

```
Name   
------  
EMPNAME
EMPID
MANAGERID (foreign key to same table)
STATUS
```

The ManagerId self join on the table causes multiple hierarchies in the system. The hierarchies will be at the max of level 5.

I need an optimal way to get all nodes in a hierarchy that may have at least one node in an active status (1,2,3).
This output will be stored in a table with similar table structure.
There may be multiple roots.

A previous attempt was using this query but it is incorrect as it did not involve recursion.

```
SELECT empname, empid
FROM   employee e
WHERE e.status in (1,2,3)
      OR
      e.managerid IN  (SELECT empid 
                       FROM   employee m
                       WHERE  e.status in (1,2,3))
```

Example scenario:

```
EMPNAME   | EMPID | MANAGERID | STATUS
:-------- | ----: | --------: | -----:
CEO       |     1 |   NULL    |      0
Mgr1      |     2 |      1    |      1
Mgr2      |     3 |      1    |      0
Mgr3      |     4 |      1    |      0
SubMgr1.1 |     5 |      2    |      0
SubMgr1.2 |     6 |      2    |      1
SubMgr2.1 |     7 |      3    |      0
SubMgr2.2 |     8 |      3    |      1
SubMgr3.1 |     9 |      4    |      0
Emp1.1.1  |    10 |      5    |      0
Emp1.1.2  |    11 |      5    |      1
Emp1.2.1  |    12 |      6    |      0
Emp1.2.2  |    13 |      6    |      1
Emp2.1.1  |    14 |      7    |      0
Emp2.1.2  |    15 |      7    |      1
Emp2.2.1  |    16 |      8    |      0
Emp2.2.2  |    17 |      8    |      1
Emp3.1.1  |    18 |      9    |      0
Emp3.1.2  |    19 |      9    |      1
```

In this example, Mgr1 has status 1
Because of this, all employees under Mgr1 and the ones who come above Mgr1 (the CEO) should be selected.

Similarly Emp3.1.2(a leaf node), is active -  so include all the managers of this Emp3.1.2 (SubMgr3.1, Mgr3, CEO) even though the above ones are inactive.

The expected Output (which is to be stored optimally in a different table):

```
EMPNAME   | EMPID | MANAGERID | STATUS
:-------- | ----: | --------: | -----:
CEO       |     1 |      null |      0
Mgr1      |     2 |         1 |      1
SubMgr1.1 |     5 |         2 |      0
Emp1.1.1  |    10 |         5 |      0
Emp1.1.2  |    11 |         5 |      1
SubMgr1.2 |     6 |         2 |      1
Emp1.2.1  |    12 |         6 |      0
Emp1.2.2  |    13 |         6 |      1
Mgr2      |     3 |         1 |      0
SubMgr2.1 |     7 |         3 |      0
Emp2.1.2  |    15 |         7 |      1
SubMgr2.2 |     8 |         3 |      1
Emp2.2.1  |    16 |         8 |      0
Emp2.2.2  |    17 |         8 |      1
Mgr3      |     4 |         1 |      0
SubMgr3.1 |     9 |         4 |      0
Emp3.1.2  |    19 |         9 |      1
```

Comment: We can create temporary tables to store data but can't modify the schema of this table.

Comment: The hierarchy is similar to the one mentioned here: [link](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql)

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful - as formatted text in your question, not as images or on another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the full unfiltered hierarchy (assuming that the top-level manager has a `NULL` value for `managerid`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
START WITH MANAGERID IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPID = MANAGERID
```

You can then filter to see if there is an active status in the hierarchy from each employee back up to the top-level manager:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  status IN (1,2,3)
  START WITH EMPID = t.EMPID
  CONNECT BY EMPID = PRIOR MANAGERID
)
START WITH MANAGERID IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPID = MANAGERID
```

Which for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( EMPNAME, EMPID, MANAGERID, STATUS ) AS
SELECT 'CEO',  1, NULL, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mgr1', 2,    1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mgr2', 3,    1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mgr3', 4,    1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SubMgr1.1', 5, 2, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SubMgr1.2', 6, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SubMgr2.1', 7, 3, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SubMgr2.2', 8, 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SubMgr3.1', 9, 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emp1.1.1', 10, 5, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emp1.1.2', 11, 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emp1.2.1', 12, 6, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emp1.2.2', 13, 6, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emp2.1.1', 14, 7, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emp2.1.2', 15, 7, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emp2.2.1', 16, 8, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emp2.2.2', 17, 8, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emp3.1.1', 18, 9, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emp3.1.2', 19, 9, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Gives the output:

> ```
> EMPNAME   | EMPID | MANAGERID | STATUS
> :-------- | ----: | --------: | -----:
> Mgr1      |     2 |         1 |      1
> SubMgr1.1 |     5 |         2 |      0
> Emp1.1.1  |    10 |         5 |      0
> Emp1.1.2  |    11 |         5 |      1
> SubMgr1.2 |     6 |         2 |      1
> Emp1.2.1  |    12 |         6 |      0
> Emp1.2.2  |    13 |         6 |      1
> Emp2.1.2  |    15 |         7 |      1
> SubMgr2.2 |     8 |         3 |      1
> Emp2.2.1  |    16 |         8 |      0
> Emp2.2.2  |    17 |         8 |      1
> Emp3.1.2  |    19 |         9 |      1
> ```

To check in both directions then just descend the hierarchy as well as ascending it:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  status IN (1,2,3)
  START WITH EMPID = t.MANAGERID
  CONNECT BY EMPID = PRIOR MANAGERID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  status IN (1,2,3)
  START WITH EMPID = t.EMPID
  CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPID = MANAGERID
)
START WITH MANAGERID IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPID = MANAGERID
```

Outputs:

> ```
> EMPNAME   | EMPID | MANAGERID | STATUS
> :-------- | ----: | --------: | -----:
> CEO       |     1 |      null |      0
> Mgr1      |     2 |         1 |      1
> SubMgr1.1 |     5 |         2 |      0
> Emp1.1.1  |    10 |         5 |      0
> Emp1.1.2  |    11 |         5 |      1
> SubMgr1.2 |     6 |         2 |      1
> Emp1.2.1  |    12 |         6 |      0
> Emp1.2.2  |    13 |         6 |      1
> Mgr2      |     3 |         1 |      0
> SubMgr2.1 |     7 |         3 |      0
> Emp2.1.2  |    15 |         7 |      1
> SubMgr2.2 |     8 |         3 |      1
> Emp2.2.1  |    16 |         8 |      0
> Emp2.2.2  |    17 |         8 |      1
> Mgr3      |     4 |         1 |      0
> SubMgr3.1 |     9 |         4 |      0
> Emp3.1.2  |    19 |         9 |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ba9c5255f40fec0fc03a7c612d8f8710)*

You could also use a recursive subquery-factoring clause to propagate the active status as you descend through the hierarchy; you'd still need to check the remaining hierarchy in the other direction if it is not active. Profile both solutions and see if one is more performant than the other as its not something we can determine.

```sql
WITH data ( empname, empid, managerid, status, is_active ) AS (
  SELECT t.empname,
         t.empid,
         t.managerid,
         t.status,
         CASE WHEN status IN (1,2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  managerid IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT t.empname,
         t.empid,
         t.managerid,
         t.status,
         CASE WHEN d.is_active = 1 OR t.status IN (1,2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM   data d
         INNER JOIN table_name t
         ON ( d.empid = t.managerid )
)
SELECT empname,
       empid,
       managerid,
       status
FROM   data d
WHERE  is_active = 1
OR     EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  t.status IN ( 1, 2, 3)
  START WITH d.empid = t.managerid
  CONNECT BY PRIOR empid = managerid
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9fa3e231884bff8d80add5e51a9ce6b3)

Comment: Thanks, but this goes on recursion in only 1 direction 
Is there a way to go top to employee (checking if one of the child is active). ?

Scenario - there are multiple CEOs and if even only the leaf Employee(under CEO x) has status Active then this hierarchy should be selected too )

CEOx                       X               **Inactive**
CTOx                       X.A            **Inactive**
ExecutiveManager  X.A.1          **inactive**
..
LeafEmployee         X.1.1......n  **active**

then select all the employees in this chain. (CEOx, CTOx,.... LeafEmployee) should be selected.

Comment: @Abhijeet - please **edit your question** to include this new requirement. Sample data (and code) is hard to read in comments due to poor formatting and lack of layout.

Comment: @MT0 will this work for 5 Million records? As per your answer, each row there will be an inner query executed, won't the complexity be N^2 ?

Comment: Of course it will work; what you mean to ask is "will it work quickly?" For that you'll have to try it as we don't have your data but there isn't another easy solution that isn't likely to be just as complex as for each data point you need to query both up and down the hierarchy so you can't simply start at the top-level managers (or at the leaf-employees) and work in a single direction.

Comment: @MT0, the JDBC client in our prod only allows for 5 minutes per execution. One plan I have is segregating the data sets by using id between range 1 to range 2
and invoking this code for multiple ranges so that 1 execution takes <5 minutes.

Comment: @Abhijeet You'll need to sort out performance issues because we don't have your hardware, data sets, etc. to be able to make that analysis.